# SQL Server: Use of Windows Function with ordered set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

With this sample dataset:

```
ID    POS    QTY      A     B
32    1       50      1     2
28    2      200      1     2
12    3      300      2     2
16    4      400      1     2
98    5      500      3     1
56    6      600      2     2
33    7      700      2     2
```

How can i get SUM(QTY) by group.  Group is based on diferent (A AND B) **ORDERED BY POS** !!!

As:

```
ID    POS    QTY      A     B       SUM(QTY)
32    1       50      1     2       250         Group 1
28    2      200      1     2       250         Group 1
12    3      300      2     2       300         Group 2
16    4      400      1     2       900         Group 3 not 1
98    5      500      1     2       900         Group 3 not 1
56    6      600      2     2       1300        Group 4 not 2
33    7      700      2     2       1300        Group 4 not 2
```

I've tried different solutions with PARTITION BY but always get Groups with same A and B summed.

Order by POS is important, as same A and B forms diferent groups.

Comment: Group by (A+B) ill not work because the combinations 2+2 = 1+3 = 3+1 etc. If you know the range of B (example B always < 10)  (10*A+B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be prettier ways to do this but this is what I've got for now:

```
declare @t table (ID int,POS int,QTY int,A int,B int)
insert into @t(ID,POS,QTY,A,B) values
(32,1, 50,1,2),    (28,2,200,1,2),    (12,3,300,2,2),    (16,4,400,1,2),
(98,5,500,1,2),    (56,6,600,2,2),    (33,7,700,2,2)

;With Origins as (
    select t1.*
    from @t t1
        left join
        @t t2
            on
                t1.POS = t2.POS + 1 and
                t1.A = t2.A and
                t1.B = t2.B
    where t2.POS is null
)
select
    t.*,SUM(t.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY o.POS) as Qty
from
    @t t
        inner join
    Origins o
        on
            t.A = o.A and
            t.B = o.B and
            t.POS >= o.POS
        left join
    Origins o_other
        on
            t.A = o_other.A and
            t.B = o_other.B and
            t.POS >= o_other.POS and
            o_other.POS > o.POS
where
    o_other.POS is null
```

Where the Origins CTE is used to find the first row for each "partition". This assumes the `POS` has no gaps - but if it does, another CTE using `ROW_NUMBER()` based on `POS` can be used in its place.

The final query then joins each row to the "correct" `Origins` row by finding the nearest such row with a lower `POS` value, and then we use that as the key for partitioning.

Result:

```
ID          POS         QTY         A           B           Qty
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
32          1           50          1           2           250
28          2           200         1           2           250
12          3           300         2           2           300
16          4           400         1           2           900
98          5           500         1           2           900
56          6           600         2           2           1300
33          7           700         2           2           1300
```

(I changed the sample data to match your expected results, rather than what is shown at the top of your question which has a `3,1` row for entry `5`).

Comment: As POS values have gaps, how would you use ROW_NUMBER() instead of POS for the Origins CTE ?

Comment: @P.A - just add a new CTE at the top `With NewT as (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by POS) as NewPOS from @t)` and then use `NewT` and `NewPOS` wherever `@t` and `POS` currently exist in the query.

Comment: Thanks, got it done, using a temp table with row_number() as you with this new CTE.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*, t2.sum_qty
from your_table t1
join
(
   select a, b, sum(qty) as sum_qty
   from your_table
   group by a, b
) t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b
order by t1.pos
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sum(qty) returns sum() for ALL rows with same A and B